# Joining 2 SQL queries into 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL queries that I would like to join into one:

```
 select d.full_month, COUNT(*) amount
    from fact_ticket t
    join dim_queue q on t.queue_id = q.queue_id 
    join vt_scopes s on t.scope_id = s.scope_id
    join dim_date d on t.create_date_id = d.date_id
    where q.name = 'Support'
    and year(GETDATE()) = YEAR(t.create_date)
    and s.statusname not in ('discarded', 'closed')
    group by d.full_month
    order by 1;
```

and

```
select d.full_month, COUNT(*) amount
from fact_ticket t
join dim_queue q on t.queue_id = q.queue_id 
join vt_scopes s on t.scope_id = s.scope_id
join dim_date d on t.create_date_id = d.date_id
where q.name = 'Support'
and year(GETDATE()) = YEAR(t.create_date)
and s.statusname in ('closed')
group by d.full_month
order by 1;
```

Both gives me now a result with a date column and an amount column, but I would like to get everything in one query where I would get date, amount 1, amount 2.

Is there an easy to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query-

```
SELECT d.full_month, 
COUNT(IF(s.statusname NOT IN ('discarded', 'closed'),1,NULL)) amount1, 
COUNT(IF(s.statusname IN ('closed'),1,NULL)) amount2 
    FROM fact_ticket t
    JOIN dim_queue q ON t.queue_id = q.queue_id 
    JOIN vt_scopes s ON t.scope_id = s.scope_id
    JOIN dim_date d ON t.create_date_id = d.date_id
    WHERE q.name = 'Support'
    AND YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(t.create_date)
    GROUP BY d.full_month
    ORDER BY 1;
```

2nd Edition: Even you can get benefit of index if exist on create_date by below query-

```
SELECT d.full_month, 
COUNT(IF(s.statusname NOT IN ('discarded', 'closed'),1,NULL)) amount1, 
COUNT(IF(s.statusname IN ('closed'),1,NULL)) amount2 
    FROM fact_ticket t
    JOIN dim_queue q ON t.queue_id = q.queue_id 
    JOIN vt_scopes s ON t.scope_id = s.scope_id
    JOIN dim_date d ON t.create_date_id = d.date_id
    WHERE q.name = 'Support'
    AND t.create_date>= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01 00:00:00') AND t.create_date <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-12-31 23:59:59');
    GROUP BY d.full_month
    ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using sum function

```
SELECT 
  d.full_month,
  SUM(s.statusname NOT IN ('discarded', 'closed')) amount,
  SUM(s.statusname = 'closed') amount_closed 
FROM
  fact_ticket t 
  JOIN dim_queue q 
    ON t.queue_id = q.queue_id 
  JOIN vt_scopes s 
    ON t.scope_id = s.scope_id 
  JOIN dim_date d 
    ON t.create_date_id = d.date_id 
WHERE q.name = 'Support' 
  AND YEAR(GETDATE ()) = YEAR(t.create_date) 
GROUP BY d.full_month 
ORDER BY 1 ;
```